# Pandas =right() on excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On pandas 1.3.4 and Python 3.9.

So I'm trying to basically do a =RIGHT() function for an entire column of the column next to it. I am currently referencing [this](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/extract-last-n-characters-from-right-of-the-column-in-pandas-python/) but I'm getting an error of `Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('file.csv', delimiter=',')

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Cost', 'Caller'])

df['Cost'] = df['Caller'].str[-10:]

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wsoC.png) is what I have, where the cost column is empty so it would be the =right() for the caller column just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNclR.png). The csv files that I'll be dealing will each have a different amount of "callers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let Pandas infer your data type else `Caller` will cast as an integer.
Use `dtype=str` as parameter of `read_table` (or read_csv?)

```
df = pd.read_table('file.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str)
```